# Crystal reports using Crystalreportwebformviewer4 in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports, viewer

Currently ASP.NET web application when report is generated to the form of web page the tool bar has default print/export buttons (gets them from `aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81/crystalreportviewers13/`).

But I need to get it from `aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/`. How can I achieve it?

This has modified user friendly buttons and functions. Is there any change I need to do in `web.config`?